# tbb.dll is missing from your computer

Tags: c++, dll, tbb, visual-c++

I have followed every step in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tz1u2Ahy4as).

Basically added all additional dependencies to Visual Studio 2010. Added tbb.lib to linker input options too. The program builds but it does not run.

I get System Error : *"The program can't start because tbb.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem."*

Did that, still getting the same error. Also saw that tbb.dll is present in the \bin directory.

Comment: Wherever tbb.dll is located, it should *not* be in a `\bin` directory.  It needs to be copied into your project's Debug directory.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. It does work. There is an Addin for TBB [here](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/ver.php?fid=129). What does this puglin do? Does it really copy the file to my debug directory? I thought all it did was to fill in the project properties. I am working on VC2010 express so cannot use the plugin.

Comment: @ShishirPandey.. the video you're talking about in 2012 no longer exist... any chance of finding it again?

Answer (score 1):

Add the path to the folder that includes the tbb.dll file (for example in my case is ..\tbb42_20131003oss\bin\ia32\vc10), into the PATH environmental variable of your PC. In this way the dll file will be accessible and usable without being necessary to copy it into the Debug (or Release) directory of your project.

Comment: I'd say that copying the file is a more straightforward way to do it, but that will work too.